# How to remove duplication in Makefile?

Tags: c, build, makefile, dry

Is there a way to simplify this sort of repetition in a Makefile?

```
duo = ./node_modules/.bin/duo

build: lib/background/build lib/page/build lib/popup/build

lib/background/build: lib/background/build/build.js lib/background/build/build.css
lib/page/build: lib/page/build/build.js lib/page/build/build.css
lib/popup/build: lib/popup/build/build.js lib/popup/build/build.css

lib/background/build/build.js: lib/background/index.js node_modules component.json
  @mkdir -p lib/background/build
  @$(duo) lib/background/index.js > lib/background/build/build.js

lib/page/build/build.js: lib/page/index.js node_modules component.json
  @mkdir -p lib/page/build
  @$(duo) lib/page/index.js > lib/page/build/build.js

lib/popup/build/build.js: lib/popup/index.js node_modules component.json
  @mkdir -p lib/popup/build
  @$(duo) lib/popup/index.js > lib/popup/build/build.js

lib/background/build/build.css: lib/background/index.css node_modules component.json
  @mkdir -p lib/background/build
  @$(duo) lib/background/index.css | $(myth) > lib/background/build/build.css

lib/page/build/build.css: lib/page/index.css node_modules component.json
  @mkdir -p lib/page/build
  @$(duo) lib/page/index.css | $(myth) > lib/page/build/build.css

lib/popup/build/build.css: lib/popup/index.css node_modules component.json
  @mkdir -p lib/popup/build
  @$(duo) lib/popup/index.css | $(myth) > lib/popup/build/build.css
```

Basically, I want to run a simple `make build` command from the top level, and it only rebuilds these subprojects if necessary. I would like to not have to use a Makefile for each subproject because that is also repetitive. Everything I've tried in relation to wildcard paths hasn't worked out, so wondering if there is even a way to do this. For example, I tried doing something like this (similar both for js and css) but no luck:

```
js = $(shell find lib test -type f -name '*.js' ! -path "*build.js")

$(js)/build/build.js: node_modules component.json
  # somehow get the directory such as lib/background based on the make command?
  local dir=$(shell dirname $(shell dirname $@))
  @mkdir -p $(dir)/build
  @$(duo) $(dir)/index.js > $(dir)/build/build.js
```

Any ideas how to make this DRY?

Comment: That attempt isn't going to work because `$(js)` is a list of filenames and so will expand in the target slot to a list of filenames with `/build/build.js` appended to the final file name in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good first start would be to stop repeating the targets/etc. in the rule bodies themselves and use the automatic variables for them instead. So `'$@'` for the target filename, `'$(@D)'` for the directory path (like `dirname`) of the target filename, etc.

Which gets you:

```
duo = ./node_modules/.bin/duo

build: lib/background/build lib/page/build lib/popup/build

lib/background/build: lib/background/build/build.js lib/background/build/build.css
lib/page/build: lib/page/build/build.js lib/page/build/build.css
lib/popup/build: lib/popup/build/build.js lib/popup/build/build.css

lib/background/build/build.js: lib/background/index.js node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) lib/background/index.js > '$@'

lib/page/build/build.js: lib/page/index.js node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) lib/page/index.js > '$@'

lib/popup/build/build.js: lib/popup/index.js node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) lib/popup/index.js > '$@'

lib/background/build/build.css: lib/background/index.css node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) lib/background/index.css | $(myth) > '$@'

lib/page/build/build.css: lib/page/index.css node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) lib/page/index.css | $(myth) > '$@'

lib/popup/build/build.css: lib/popup/index.css node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) lib/popup/index.css | $(myth) > '$@'
```

Then realizing that [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) are helpful when you have targets and prerequisites that share filename patterns and similar rule bodies you can start using those too. They also give you an extra [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

You get this (intermediate) stage:

```
duo = ./node_modules/.bin/duo

build: lib/background/build lib/page/build lib/popup/build

lib/background/build: lib/background/build/build.js lib/background/build/build.css
lib/page/build: lib/page/build/build.js lib/page/build/build.css
lib/popup/build: lib/popup/build/build.js lib/popup/build/build.css

%/build/build.js: %/index.js node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.js > '$@'

%/build/build.js: %/index.js node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.js > '$@'

%/build/build.js: %/index.js node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.js > '$@'

%/build/build.css: %/index.css node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.css | $(myth) > '$@'

%/build/build.css: %/index.css node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.css | $(myth) > '$@'

%/build/build.css: %/index.css node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.css | $(myth) > '$@'
```

And them you see that you've really just got two duplicate rules so you combine them.

```
duo = ./node_modules/.bin/duo

build: lib/background/build lib/page/build lib/popup/build

lib/background/build: lib/background/build/build.js lib/background/build/build.css
lib/page/build: lib/page/build/build.js lib/page/build/build.css
lib/popup/build: lib/popup/build/build.js lib/popup/build/build.css

%/build/build.js: %/index.js node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.js > '$@'

%/build/build.css: %/index.css node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.css | $(myth) > '$@'
```

And then, since make doesn't handle directory targets/prerequisites as well as one might like, you can drop the `lib/background/build`, `lib/page/build`, and `lib/popup/build` intermediate targets and just list the actual files as the prereqs for `build`.

```
duo = ./node_modules/.bin/duo

build: lib/background/build/build.js lib/background/build/build.css \
       lib/page/build/build.js lib/page/build/build.css \
       lib/popup/build/build.js lib/popup/build/build.css

%/build/build.js: %/index.js node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.js > '$@'

%/build/build.css: %/index.css node_modules component.json
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(duo) '$*'/index.css | $(myth) > '$@'
```

I should probably mention that I didn't test this (for lack of desire to mock up the directory layout/etc.) but the transformations were straight-forward and the concepts are fairly simple so it should work just fine. But anything is possible.

To clean up the `build` prerequisites you could use something like:

```
build: $(foreach d,background page popup,$(addprefix lib/$d/build/,build.js build.css))
```

Comment: Dude, no way. You are a master! This is so cool, cleans up so much.

Comment: Is there any way to cleanup the `build: <deps>` dependencies, so they are patterned too? Something like `build: %/build/build.js %/build/build.css`? That doesn't seem to work for me. `make: *** No rule to make target '%/build/build.js', needed by 'build'.  Stop.`

Comment: Yeah, that isn't going to work that way. You can clean it up some with some make functions if you want to. Hold on.

Comment: any ideas how to get this to work? `%/build/build.js: %/index.js %/lib/*.js node_modules component.json`, where with that `%/lib/*.js` I want it to match all javascript files relative to `%/lib`, which could be `lib/page/lib/*.js` or `lib/popup/lib/*.js`, etc. Getting some weird behavior with it though, not working right.

Comment: follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539561/can-you-do-wildcard-c-in-a-makefile