# Can you do $(wildcard %/**/*.c) in a makefile?

Tags: unix, makefile, wildcard

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536683/how-to-remove-duplication-in-makefile), there is one more case I haven't been able to figure out in a few hours of tinkering.

Here is what the makefile currently looks like:

```
output = $(shell find lib -type f -name '*build.js' -or -name '*build.css')
myth = ./node_modules/.bin/myth
duo = ./node_modules/.bin/duo

build: $(output)

%/build/build.js: %/index.js %/lib/*.js node_modules component.json
  @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
  @$(duo) '$*'/index.js > '$@'

%/build/build.css: %/index.css %/lib/*.css node_modules component.json
  @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
  @$(duo) '$*'/index.css | $(myth) > '$@'

node_modules: package.json
  @n 0.11.13
  @npm install
  @touch node_modules # make sure folder is updated later than package.json
```

The piece that I have added on top of the great answer in that other question is the `%/lib/*.js` and `%/lib/*.css` right here:

```
%/build/build.js: %/index.js %/lib/*.js node_modules component.json
```

That seems to work fine if you have all the required files, meaning the directory structure looks like this:

```
component.json
lib/
lib/page/
lib/page/build/
lib/page/build/build.js
lib/page/index.js
lib/page/lib/
lib/page/lib/a.js
lib/page/lib/b.js
lib/popup/
lib/popup/build/
lib/popup/build/build.js
lib/popup/index.js
lib/popup/lib/
lib/popup/lib/a.js
lib/popup/lib/b.js
node_modules/
package.json
```

With that current make task, it rebuilds the proper subproject/folder (page/popup/etc.) if you change a file inside that folder. However, it *doesn't* rebuild if you are *missing one of the dependencies*.

For example, in the following folder structure, the "popup" subproject will build fine (because it still has all the required target dependencies). However, the "page" subproject won't ever build, because it is missing any `%/lib/*.js` files:

```
component.json
lib/
lib/page/
lib/page/build/
lib/page/build/build.js
lib/page/index.js
lib/popup/
lib/popup/build/
lib/popup/build/build.js
lib/popup/index.js
lib/popup/lib/
lib/popup/lib/a.js
lib/popup/lib/b.js
node_modules/
package.json
```

So, in this situation, the only way it will build is if you have both an `%/index.js` and some file matching `%/lib/*.js`.

My question is, how do you make it work for both cases?

Essentially all I want is to rebuild a subproject if any of the files *except ones in build/build.js* change. That is, if any file has changed that *doesn't match the target name*, then run the task.

How do you do this?

I have tried this:

```
%/build/build.js: %/**/*.js node_modules component.json
```

But that errors out with this:

```
make: Circular lib/page/build/build.js <- lib/page/build/build.js dependency dropped.
```

Because it matches the target name.

It also seems like it might be possible to use `$(filter pattern, text)` or `$(filter-out, pattern, text)`, but I haven't been successful with those.

```
%/build/build.js: $(filter-out %/build/build.js, %/**/*.js) node_modules component.json
```

That seemed like it might include all files matching `%/**/*.js` (so `lib/page/index.js`, and `lib/page/lib/a.js` if that was present), and just exclude `lib/page/build/build.js`. But, I haven't had any luck with that, maybe I'm just using it incorrectly.

How do you get this to work?

Comment: does this have anything to do with secondary expansion? http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html

Comment: I think this is [Pitfalls of Using Wildcards](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Pitfall) (at least in part).

Comment: what if you instead did it something like this: `build/%.js: $(filter lib/%/**/*.js, $(js)) node_modules component.json`? still haven't nailed it yet..