# Can you use the % inside $(shell find) in Make?

Tags: unix, path, makefile, dry

At this point I want to just find something that works ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536683/how-to-remove-duplication-in-makefile) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539561/can-you-do-wildcard-c-in-a-makefile), not necessary to read though, this current question should be much simpler).

I want to create a make task that works on subdirectories, with a dynamic (unknown) number of subfiles. Can you do this in make?

```
build/%.js: $(shell find apps/% -type f -name '*.js')
```

Say you want the final directory tree to look like this:

```
build/
build/page.js
build/popup.js
apps/
apps/page/
apps/page/index.js
apps/page/lib/
apps/page/lib/a.js
apps/page/lib/b.js
apps/popup/
apps/popup/index.js
```

When you change any of the `index.js` files, or the files nested inside `lib/*.js`, then the corresponding folder should rebuild.

How do you do that with `make`? Without being repetitive, it's straightforward to do if you have a bunch of similar build tasks that aren't DRY.

I have also tried this:

```
build/%.js: apps/%/index.js apps/%/lib/*.js
```

But that only works if there exists a `lib/*.js` in every project. The "popup" project in the example directory tree above doesn't have that, so it never builds.

So basically, those targets need to be "optional". A simple example is this:

```
build.js: $(shell find apps -type f -name '*.js')
```

That would create a `build.js` file if *any* `*.js` file inside the `apps/` folder changed. Basically that's what I'm going for, the main difference being I want to have a *variable name* involved:

```
build/%.js: $(shell find apps/% -type f -name '*.js')
```

But that doesn't work because it seems the `%` isn't evaluated inside the `$(shell)` function (not sure how that is supposed to work or where that's documented). But essentially, that's all I want to do.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the prereqs for each target that matches `build/%.js` "manually" and still keep the common `build/%.js` target rule to build them.

```
APPS := $(subst apps/,,$(wildcard apps/*))

TARGETS := $(patsubst %,build/%.js,$(APPS))

all: $(TARGETS)

# Add prerequisites (based on $(wildcard) output) to each target file.
$(foreach app,$(APPS),$(eval build/$(app).js: $(wildcard apps/$(app)/lib/*.js)))

build/%.js: apps/%/index.js
        @echo 'Building $@ from $^'
```